# How to run a cron job every some hours every some minutes

Tags: cron

I want to run a cron job every some hours every some minutes. For example, every 2 hours every 25 minutes or every 5 hours every 20 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood you correctly but you could define query such as:

```
0 0/25 0/2 1/1 * ? *
```

You can evaluate this query somewhere in the internet, for example here: [click](http://www.cronmaker.com/)